# Unable to fetch data from test rail using java

Tags: java, selenium, testing, testrail

I am using the API provided by Test rail to pull info using java.
Below is my program.

APIClient client = new APIClient("https://test.testrail.net/index.php?/runs/view/154");
client.setUser("..");

client.setPassword("..");

```
JSONObject c = (JSONObject) client.sendGet("get_case/T54757");
System.out.println(c);
```

I downloaded the API and called the method as mentioned above.But every time the json response is returning null.
Could any body please help?

Comment: have you manually tried hitting the api? do you get results then?

Comment: No @kushal. I hven't tried that yet.

Comment: Try and share...

Comment: I am giving the request in this format                                                     
 GET index.php?/api/v2/get_case/:case_id
https://test.testrail.net/index.php?/runs/view/154/get_case/T54552                                   its saying "Not authorized".                                                                                       May be I am doing something wrong.

Comment: yup the problem is in your api call

Answer (score 0):

As per TestRail API V2- one needs to use TYPE= Basic Authentication and UserName=  and Password=<your testrail password or API key, if enabled>

It's strongly advised to enable API key and use it when accessing with code for security reasons. Whole collections of API calls, working fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of potential issues with your code, but they should be pretty easy fixes. First, you should initialize the client with just the base URL for the API, without writing any specific endpoint. After that, update the case ID to be totally numeric, without the `T` or `C` prefix.

Here’s what that might look like based on the code you shared:

```
APIClient client = new APIClient("https://test.testrail.net/index.php?/api/v2");
JSONObject c = (JSONObject) client.sendGet("get_case/54757");
```

To test the request manually (i.e. using Postman), you could use something like the example below and pass your TestRail username/password as Basic Authentication:

```
GET https://test.testrail.net/index.php?/api/v2/get_case/123
```

See the get_case documentation reference for more details:
https://www.gurock.com/testrail/docs/api/reference/cases/#getcase